# Ruby block cannot seem to access local scope variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, block

I'm writing a function that reads in an answer key, creates a question, and then associates the right answer with that questions.  Here's my function:

```
def self.save_images_in_dir(dir)
  answer_key_file = Dir.glob(dir+"/*.{rtf,txt}").first
  answer_key = Array.new
  if answer_key_file
    puts "found key"
    File.open(answer_key_file, "r") do |infile|
        while (line = infile.gets)
            if line.match(/^\d+[.]\s+/)
              num = line.match(/\d+/)
              answer = line.gsub(/\d+[.]\s+/,"")  # Take out the 1. 
              answer.chomp!
              answer_key.push(answer.to_s)#answer_key[num.to_s]=answer.to_s
              puts "number #{num} is #{answer.to_s}"
            end
        end
    end
  end


  images = Dir.glob("#{dir}*.{png,jpeg,jpg,gif}").sort_by {|file| File.ctime(file) }

  counter = 0 

  answer_key.each do |q|
    puts "before entering: #{q}"
  end
  images.each do |img|
    q = self.new
    q.tags = get_tags(img)
    q.correct_answer = answer_key[counter]
    puts "---------Answer is:#{answer_key[counter]}--------\n"
    q.photo = File.open(img)


    if q.correct_answer.nil?
      puts "answer is nil"
    end

    counter = counter + 1 
  end
end
```

and here's a snippet of the output right before it enters the images.each block.

before entering: D

before entering: A

before entering: A

before entering: C

before entering: A

found key

---------Answer is:--------

answer is nil

Does anyone know why answer_key would "reset", and, furthermore, why answer_key.count would return 0 when evaluated within the images block? I understand that blocks should inherit the local scope from where they are called...any reason why answer_key would not be passed?

Comment: Are you sure this is the complete code you're running? There is no reason why within the block you showed to us it should be "reset" at all.

Comment: Does the 'puts "number #{num} is #{answer.to_s}"' line output several times?

Answer (score 3):

The mistake must be somewhere else, this code should work.

Write a few unit tests and refactor this method, it's trying to do too many things.

Also, when you loop over the images, you can get rid of `counter` and use `each_with_index` instead.

Comment: Yea, it seems like that's the issue. Just found out the code runs fine on one of my friend's computers but not on mine.  We have the same version of ruby and rails installed as well.